# How to install wget using Amazon Linux 2 server?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to install CUDA in my container, but, since the `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8` doesn't have `wget` distribution, I'm getting the following error: `/bin/sh: apt-get: command not found`

Dockerfile:

```
# Pull the base image with python 3.8 as a runtime for your Lambda
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

# Copy the earlier created requirements.txt file to the container
COPY requirements.txt ./

# Install the python requirements from requirements.txt
RUN python3.8 -m pip install -r requirements.txt 

# Create the model directory for mounting the EFS 
RUN mkdir -p /mnt/ml

# Install CUDA
RUN apt-get install wget
RUN wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/libcudnn8_8.1.0.77-1+cuda11.2_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i libcudnn8_8.1.0.77-1+cuda11.2_amd64.deb

# Copy the earlier created app.py file to the container
COPY app.py ./
COPY maskrcnn/ ./maskrcnn

# Set the CMD to your handler
CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```

To run my project I am using I am using Amazon Linux 2 as my server.

Do I need to install another image in order to install cuda inside my docker? If yes, what would be the most appropriate image for this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to use the Debian/Ubuntu package manager on a Docker image that is based on an AWS Docker image which uses a completely different package manager (Yum).

Maybe change your RUN command to this:

`RUN yum -y install wget`

However, even after doing this I think you will find you will not be able to find a package to satisfy libcudnn8.

As the true solution to your problem I would suggest you change your base image to ubuntu as this is what your Docker image is more likely suited to by simply renaming the FROM section of your Dockerfile as follows:

`FROM ubuntu:latest`

Comment: Following your answer I was able to run `RUN wget https://---.deb`, but my problem now is that I get the following: `No package dpkg available`, when I try execute `RUN yum -y install dpkg`. Any suggestions?

Comment: 'dpkg' is part of the Debian/Ubuntu package manager - you are currently using the 'Yum' package manager which is part of the AWS docker image.  Please change your FROM statement as I have already suggested to convert the AWS Docker image to Ubuntu which will also change your package manager from the 'Yum' to the 'Apt' package manager.  This will likely solve your problems.